# Configurar o Cordova SQLite Storage

Tags: apache-cordova

Não estou conseguindo configurar o plugin [Cordova SQLite Storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage). Os passos que sigo são:

1. Instalar o plugin com `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage`
2. Copiar **SQLitePlugin.js** de dentro da pasta do plugin.
3. Configuro as seguintes permissões:

*AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Depois faço a chamada:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db", location: 1});
```

Aí dá erro, informando que não informando que não foi possível abrir o banco de dados. Não sei se está faltando alguma configuração.

Alguém aí já passou por algo desse tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Um pouco tarde para resposta mas talvez ajude.
Se você esta tentando executar o aplicativo no navegador ele não vai funcionar.
Você precisa rodar o aplicativo no celular e fazer o debug no chrome.

```
cordova run android -1
```

e no chrome acessar
 `chrome://inspect`

Answer (score 0):

No site do Plugin indica que a função a ser utilizada é sqlitePlugin.openDatabase() sem o window na frente.
Outro ponto é que essa chama só funciona após o evento deviceready().

Até onde entendi na documentação você tem que criar um arquivo sqllite em outro aplicativo como o SQLliteBrowser e colocar o arquivo criado no diretório www.

Tenho o ambiente instalado na minha maquina e tentei replicar o exemplo que você passou, e apesar de todas as tentativas acima também estou tendo o mesmo erro, o que poderia indicar um Bug no Plugin.

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo erro. De qualquer forma, obrigado Vitor.

Comment: Algum progresso? com mais dados podemos tentar responder melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Consegui Vitor. Instalei o plugin pela ferramenta CLI e gerei o apk.
O problema é que o plugin não funciona no phonegap developer, só gerando o apk mesmo.
Subi o exemplo do projeto de teste para https://github.com/markosbarbosa/exemplo-sqliteplugin

Se quiser sugerir alguma coisa fique a vontade.

Muito obrigado!